# Return the previous value with Cloud functions (firestore)

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My application (React) uses the service of Firestore. When a user changes his username, I must verify that this username is unique. For that, I want to use a Cloud function for more reliability.
However, my function always goes into an infinite loop. I don't see how I can get out of it.

Here is my function.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
exports.checkUsername = functions.firestore
.document('/users/{userId}')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
  const before = change.before.data();
  const after = change.after.data();
  if (after.username === before.username) {
    return null;
  }
  db.collection('users').where('username', '==', after.username).get()
    .then((query) => {
      if (!query.empty) {
        // Username not available
        return change.before.ref.update({ username: before.username });
      }
      // Username available
      return null;
    })
    .catch(() => {
      return change.before.ref.update({ username: before.username });
    })
});
```

Comment: clearly is a problem with your after and before username values. After in the new name?

Comment: Thank you! 
The problem definitely comes from modifying the new value by the previous one. We are entering an infinite loop that I do not know how to stop.

Answer (score 2):

You're not dealing with promises correctly.  Your function needs to return a promise that resolves after all the asynchronous work is complete.  That's how Cloud Functions knows it's [safe to terminate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) and clean up.  Right now your function returns nothing in the case where the before and after usernames are not equal.

Minimally, you should return the final promise from the chain:

```
return db.collection('users').where('username', '==', after.username).get()
  .then(...)
  .catch(...)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to return the resolved Promise for each case but I still get this infinite loop. I don't see any way to avoid that :(